# Google map api intigration with jquery slide has animation glitches

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, google-api

I have a google map inside a sliding div.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusjh5qk/)

When you first slide down the map you'll notice that a little glitch or animation getting jerky/clunky when you click. Any idea how to fix this? Any suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  $('.map-triangle').find('div').click(function() {
    $('.map-slide').slideToggle('slow');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  });

});
```

```css
.map-triangle {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 70px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.map-triangle > div {
  background: green;
  background-size: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 4px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.map-triangle > div:hover {
  /*cursor: pointer;*/
}
.map-anchor:hover > .map-triangle > div {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.map-slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#map-canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 2">
    <a href="#" class="map-anchor">
      <div class="map-triangle">
        <div>
          map
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 map-slide">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help is really appreciated. Code snippet works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of This bad animation is that u make animation and initialization of the map at the same time so it loads when animating. i added this in your code

```
 $('.map-triangle').find('div').click(function() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
      $('.map-slide').slideToggle('slow', function(){
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      });
  });
```

with this example you will see that animation is much better.

you are even reinitializing map when sliding up, you must not.

try to write slide down and slide up events, not toggle